# Javascript assignment won't do anything in the browser

Tags: javascript

The assignment instructions:

> Create a page with a  block in the  section of the
>   document. This script should include the following:
>
> Create a function named whileTest(). Inside the function, create a
>   variable named number and assign it a value between 1 and 10. Create
>   another variable named answer and assign it a value of zero. Then
>   create a while loop. Create code that will cause the loop to execute
>   as long as the number variable does not equal the answer variable.
>   Inside the loop, assign the answer variable the return value from a
>   prompt dialog box. The prompt will ask the user to guess a number
>   between 1 and 10. The loop will continue until the proper answer is
>   entered. After the loop exits, use an alert dialog box to inform the
>   user of a correct guess.

HERE'S MY CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lab 4-1</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function whileTest (){
var number = 1, 10;
var answer = 0;
}

while (number != answer) {
alert("Please enter a number between 1 and 10");
var answer = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.",""); 
}

if (answer==number)
 alert("You have entered the correct guess!!");    

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Go read your previous lessons on: how to create a random number between 1 and 10 (your `number` var is set to 10)

Comment: Why are you displaying both a prompt and an alert? Does the user really need to be told twice?

Comment: What `var number = 1, 10;` was supposed to do?

Comment: You don't need the `if` test at the end. The loop doesn't end until they're equal.

Comment: Ok, I changed the variable number to: var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);  right? As far as the prompt and alert, that is how we did it on an assignment from last week so I just assumed that it would be the same this week.  With the if statement, do I just omit that and keep the alert following it?

Comment: ah c'mon...can't the final output expound on user's mystical powers??

Comment: @lostsock: that was already part of the code that I didn't add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code with comments pointing out your mistakes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function whileTest() {
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // <- create a number between 1 and 10
    var answer = 0;

    while (number != answer) { // <- this part also belongs to the function "whileTest()"
        // no need to call "alert" here
        answer = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.",""); // no need to create a new variable here (remove that "var")
    }
    // the while loop stops if number and answer are equal, so there is no need to check that again
    alert("You have entered the correct guess!!"); 
}
whileTest(); // call the function
</script>
```

Comment: So, I wasn't TOO far off! Thank you so much!